# Theme options save routine clashes with plugin save

Tags: theme-development

I've got an issue in which my theme's save options routine is being called when a plugin options page (contact form 7) is being saved. This throws an error that points to my "for each" loop inside my theme options save.

Am I doing something wrong here?

```
add_action('admin_menu', 'mytheme_admin');

/* ADMIN PANEL
**********************************/
function mytheme_admin()
{
    global $themename, $shortname, $options; 

    if (isset($_REQUEST['action']) && 'save' == $_REQUEST['action']) 
        {
            foreach ($options as $value) 
            {
                if( isset( $value['id'] ) && isset( $_REQUEST[$value['id']] ) ) 
                {
                    update_option( $value['id'], stripslashes($_REQUEST[$value['id']])  ); 
                }
                else
                {
                    if(isset($value['id'])) {update_option( $value['id'], "");}
                }
            }
        }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

maybe you have to change the structure of your theme options page and use [add_theme_page()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_theme_page) to avoid this type of problems

```
/* REGISTER THEME OPTION PAGE */

if ( ! function_exists( 'RMH_admin_menu' ) ):  
function RMH_admin_menu() {
  global $theme_name;
  add_theme_page( 'Opções para o tema '.$theme_name, 'Temas Opções', 'edit_theme_options', 'RMH-theme-options', 'RMH_theme_options' );
} 
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'RMH_admin_menu' );
endif;


/* DISPLAY PAGE OPTIONS*/
    function RMH_theme_options() {
      global $theme_name;
    ?>
      <div class="wrap">
          <div><br></div>
          <h2>Opções para o tema <span class="theme-option-name"><?php echo $theme_name; ?><span></h2>

          <form method="post" action="options.php">
              <?php wp_nonce_field( 'update-options' ); ?>
              <?php settings_fields( 'RMH-theme-options' ); ?>
              <?php do_settings_sections( 'RMH-theme-options' ); ?>
              <?php submit_button(); ?>
          </form>
      </div>
    <?php
    }
```